# Hardware Acceleration isn't working in Google Chrome inside Debian VM

Tags: google-chrome, virtualbox, debian, gpu, hardware-acceleration

I am having an issue where Google Chrome's hardware acceleration is not working in Google Chrome inside a Debian VM.

3D Acceleration is enabled in Virtualbox's configuration for Debian. macOS the host operating system has the latest updates installed.

Virtualbox's Guest Additions and Drivers are successfully installed and loaded.

```
nathanielsuchy@debian:~$ lsmod | grep 'vbox'
vboxsf                 45056  0
vboxguest             286720  7 vboxsf
vboxvideo              36864  3
ttm                    98304  1 vboxvideo
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 vboxvideo
drm                   360448  6 vboxvideo,ttm,drm_kms_helper
```

Hardware acceleration is enabled in Google Chrome, I even toggled it off and back on to see if that would help. I also tried overriding Chrome's GPU Blacklist but to not avail.

Finally `chrome://gpu` shows me the following:
[image: screenshot]

It's either not available or disabled. How might I go about fixing this? I would like to be able to use hardware video decoding rather than maxing the CPU Cores.

Comment: Looks like [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12746). At least it has pointers to where to look at.

Answer (score 4):

enable "Override software rendering list" on chrome://flags

Comment: This worked perfectly to enable background blurring in google meets within a virtual machine.